# Convert the following snippet into if-else statement

Tags: java, conditional-operator

How to convert this code snippet into if-else? Please help.

```
char x = ‘a’; int m; 
m = (x==’a’) ? ‘A’ : ‘a’;
```

Comment: `if (x == 'a') m = 'A'; else m = 'a';`

Comment: Start by using compilable code.

Comment: here m is int type how 'A' or 'a' can be assigned to m.

Comment: @NoorKhan Java allows auto-casting from a smaller to a higher type. So, when a char is assigned to int , the int variable will hold the ascii value of the char.

For Example : int x = 'a';
when you print this, the ascii value of 'a' (97) gets printed.

For more explanation : refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-java-examples/

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(x == 'a') ? 'A' : 'a'` is called a *ternary* expression.  Here is your code snippet using an `if-else` version:

```java
char x = 'a';
int m;

if (x == 'a') {
    m = 'A';
}
else {
    m = 'a';
}
```